# iOS How to set IB custom class to a Category

Tags: ios, class, inheritance, categories, uitableview

I currently have 2 uitableview cells that both share the same base class. However, the 2 cells have different labels and buttons in them, so they need different header files. I have tried to fix my problem by creating 2 categories that extend the base class and setting each cell's class to its respective category. However, this does not work. Does anyone have any fixes?

Thanks in advanced

[image]

Chat_TableViewCell & Invite_TableViewCell share the base class MCSwipeTableViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the custom class to a category, because a category doesn't change the class of an object, it merely adds new methods to a previously defined class.  Your cells will all be of the same class at runtime, only the method lookup table will be expanded by the category.

You will need to create actual subclasses of your `MCSwipeTableCell` class for your two cell types.